# Word for most, or best of something

Tags: word-choice

Whats the word for when one says a thing is the best of something?

E.g. the word covers all following:

- That is the *most amazing*
- It is the *coolest*
- We are *the greatest* at this

This word does exist, I just cant get it off the tip of my tongue!

Comment: There are dozens and dozens of synonyms for "the best". If you're thinking of a particular one, you're going to either have to give us more hints (initial letter? related words? free association?). Or are you looking for word which describes such words? In that case, you might be looking for *superlative*?

Comment: @DanBron if you'd like to make that an answer I can do the needful. ta.

Comment: No problem. Will do in a little while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was "superlative"
Thanks @DanBron